# How to bring outer values inside an array iteration

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON in the shape

```
[
  {
    a:1,
    b: [2,3]
  },
  {
    a:4,
    b: [5,6]
  }
]
```

That I want to transform in the shape

```
[
  [
    {
      a: 1,
      b: 2,
    },
    {
      a: 1,
      b: 3,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      a: 4,
      b: 5,
    },
    {
      a: 4,
      b: 6,
    },
  ],
]
```

That is I want to bring the value of the field `a` inside the array.

how can I do this with jq?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
jq 'map([{a,b:.b[]}])'
```

As @pmf pointed out, you can also update object :

```
jq 'map([.b=.b[]])'
```

Comment: And the update case ("bring inside the array") could be `jq 'map([.b=.b[]])'`.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the items using [variable binding](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Variable/SymbolicBindingOperator:...as$identifier%7C...) with `as`.

Then either update `.b` to have the value of its items using the [update operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:%7C=) `|=`:

```sh
jq 'map([.b[] as $b | .b |= $b])'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/MeKpfPv_Z6)

Or create completely new objects from data collected:

```sh
jq 'map(.a as $a | [.b[] as $b | {$a,$b}])'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/EUt9SSFeV7)

```json
[
  [
    {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 2
    },
    {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 3
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "a": 4,
      "b": 5
    },
    {
      "a": 4,
      "b": 6
    }
  ]
]
```